# How can I connect to MongoDB on a Dokku host?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, dokku

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 droplet running on Digital Ocean. I am running MongoDB 3.2.10 as a service, and dokku 0.7.2 running a node.js application.

How can I connect to the MongoDB service running on the host outside the app container? I would like to do this without exposing the MongoDB service publicly if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet in my opinion would be to setup a Private IP on your mongoDB Droplet and Your Dokku host and do some routing or port forwarding from the dokku host to the mongoDB Host.

Ideally though you could backup the mongoDB and restore it to a dokku managed mongo instance.

Install the Plugin

```
# dokku plugin:install https://github.com/dokku/dokku-mongo
```

Import your DB

```
# dokku mongo:import database < database.dump.tar
```

Link to your App

```
# dokku mongo:link app database
```